# Java Else if slot machine not checking if all the numbers are the same

Tags: java, if-statement

I am creating a simple slot machine program, the problem is that the `else if` statement is not checking if all three numbers are the same. I'm not quite sure what the problem is, because whenever three numbers are the same, it just prints "Two of your numbers match" instead of saying *perfect* match.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
public class SlotMachine {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random random = new Random();
    int slot1, slot2, slot3;

    String choice;

    System.out.println("Slot Machine Started!");

    do{
        slot1 = random.nextInt(2);
        slot2 = random.nextInt(2);
        slot3 = random.nextInt(2);
        System.out.println(slot1+"||"+slot2+"||"+slot3);

        //Two Matches 
        if(slot1 == slot2 || slot1==slot3||slot2==slot3) {
            System.out.println("You got two matches!");
        //All Matches
        }else if (slot1==slot2 && slot2==slot3){
            System.out.println("Perfect Match!! You win");
        }else {
            System.out.println("No matches, you suck!");
        }

        System.out.println("Would you like to spin again?");
        choice = scan.nextLine();
    }while(!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("No"));

            System.out.println("Slot Machine Stopped!");
    scan.close();
}

 }
```

Comment: Just check for perfect match first... (If you have a perfect match, you will always have two that are equal, which is being checked first)

Answer (score 4):

The problem is with the way that you organized your conditions: every time there is a three-number match, it's also a two-number match, so you should put the more restrictive check *ahead* of the less restrictive one:

```
//All Matches
if(slot1==slot2 && slot2==slot3) {
    System.out.println("Perfect Match!! You win");
}else if (slot1 == slot2 || slot1==slot3||slot2==slot3){
    System.out.println("You got two matches!");
}else {
    System.out.println("No matches, you suck!");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is easier to spot if you can read your code path in plain language. You would simply just want to switch your first and second conditionals to fix this problem.

```
I have numbers a,b,c

if a = b or a = c or b = c // This is also true in the case of all matches, so the code will stop executing this conditional here
    //I have two matches
else if a = b and b = c
    //I have all matches
else
    //have no matches
```

Comment: "execution plan", you DBA, you. :)

Comment: No, no, it's fine, I like it. :) Good answer.